How to get progress data of a SCORM Package rendering into an iframe tag, in React
I have some SCORM 2004 & SOCRM 1.2 Packages, generated through Articulate.
I have rendered them in an iframe.
And want to track the progress
I have rendered the SCORM Package in an iframe and want to track following progress.

Total count of Slides
Current Slide Count when press on Next/Prev buttons
Completion Status
Score of quiz if SCORM contains quiz assessments.

